# Range.Find on a Date That is a Formula

Tags: vba, excel, date

I receive a workbook that contains information about the processing volumes of a call center team. I have no way of modifying the format or layout of the workbook upstream.

One sheet contains information about processing errors.
[image: screenshot]
(team members' user IDs redacted)

Each date is represented by a merged 1x3 range with the date in question formatted as "dd-mmm" e.g. "01-Jun"

That date is pulled via formula from another sheet with the same layout. The formula for one such range reads: `='QA Scores'!K2:M2`

I attempted to use `Range.Find` to locate the first day of a given month and an end date in that same month (based on user input) - e.g. June 1 through June 15.

```vb
Set rngMin = .Find(What:=DateValue(minDate), _
                   LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                   LookAt:=xlWhole)
```

In other uses, I located a date in this manner, but the added complexity of the value coming from a formula seems to be the issue here.

**UPDATE:**
I have written the following based on Ron Rosenfeld's answer:

```vb
Dim UsedArr As Variant: UsedArr = SrcWS.UsedRange
blFound = False
For i = LBound(UsedArr, 1) To UBound(UsedArr, 1)
    For j = LBound(UsedArr, 2) To UBound(UsedArr, 2)
        If UsedArr(i, j) = MinDate Then
            blFound = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If blFound = True Then Exit For
Next
```

Comment: `Range.Find` persists its optional parameters between calls - a nasty bug-prone behavior; make sure you specify all parameters every time to avoid it biting you.

Comment: if you want to find an expression of a formula, wouldn't `xlValues` the right way?

Comment: @Mat'sMug thanks for that information. In this case, that's not an issue, but good to know for the future.
@DirkReichel sadly, no. `xlValues` only examines the `.Text` property of what's displayed on the worksheet.

Comment: and searching for `Format(DateValue(minDate),"[$-en-US]dd-mmm")` with `xlValues` also does not work?

Comment: Bizarrely, no, that does not work. Which actually suggests that `xlValues` is looking at more than just the `.Text` property...

Comment: My suggestion to your code would be `UsedArr = SrcWS.UsedRange.Value2`  and `If UsedArr(i, j) = CDbl(MinDate)`  `Value2` is a bit faster, and completely removes any formatting issues from consideration.  `Value` will work, but requires more conversions internally to equate.

Comment: Thanks - I made the switch. The code runs quickly and produces the expected outcome.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Dates are tricky to find with the `Range.Find` method.  One of the issues is that in VBA, dates are of the `Date` data type, but the worksheet does not have that data type.  Rather the data type is a number that is formatted to look like a date.

One solution, if you can be certain of the format of the date on the worksheet, is to search for the string equivalent.  Given your example, something like this will work:

```
Option Explicit
Sub GetDates()
    Const findDate As Date = #5/11/2017#
    Dim findStr As String

Dim R As Range, WS As Worksheet
Set WS = Worksheets("Sheet1")

findStr = Format(findDate, "dd-mmm")

With WS
    Set R = .Cells.Find(what:=findStr, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not R Is Nothing Then MsgBox findDate & " found in " & R.Address
End With

End Sub
```

but it is not very robust since, in many cases, the user can change the format.

Another method that is more robust, would be to loop through the existing cells, looking for the numeric representation of the date (using the `Value2` property):

```
Sub GetDates2()
    Const findDate As Date = #5/11/2017#
    Dim R As Range, C As Range, WS As Worksheet

Set WS = Worksheets("sheet1")
Set R = WS.UsedRange

For Each C In R
    If C.Value2 = CDbl(findDate) Then MsgBox findDate & " found in " & C.Address
Next C
End Sub
```

If you have a large range to search, this can be sped up by a factor of ten by reading the range into a VBA array and looping through the array.

Comment: Yes, the second method is pretty much bullet-proof, especially in your situation.

Comment: I don't understand why, but that first method does not work.

The second method, however, does. I have added the code I wrote to do this to my original post. Thanks!

Comment: In short, never use Range.Find to find dates.

Answer (score 1):

@KOstvall,, I would like to suggest this simple find method, since you are trying to get the Date.

Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A:A").Find("1/1/2017", LookIn:=xlValue, LookAt:=xlWhole)

Comment: No, this does not work, because in this case, the `xlFormulas` value is the formula and not the date.

Comment: This help you to find the Date. 


Private Sub Finddate ()
 
Dim dateval
, Dim Date row, Dim DateCol


dateval = Range("A8").Value
    
Cells.Find(What:=dateval, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
xlPart,SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
        
DateRow = ActiveCell.Row
DateCol = ActiveCell.Column
    
MsgBox (DateRow & "   " & DateCol)

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Been facing the same issue when using `.find` for dates. Even if the Target Date Format for search is in `dd-mmm` Use .find with `d-mmm` format.

```
Date_Value = Application.Text(Date_Value, "d-mmm-yy") 'Use Format for your case

Set r_gt= .Range(EODate_Range).Find(Date_Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
```

PS: If the target date format is `dd-mm-yy`, you'll have to loop through the cells.
Tried the above code for `01-01-20` after changing search format to `d-mm-yy` / `d-m-yy` and it failed to find the date, but it finds the date if cell format is changed to `01-Jan-20`.

Answer (score 0):

After scratching my head around this problem, I found out simple solution. The trick is just to use `Application.Match()`. *Do not* use `WorksheetFunction.Match()`, because `Application.Match()` has one BIG advantage when value is not found:

• `Application.Match()` simply returns `Error` object, and you can test for it with `IsError()` function

•`WorksheetFunction.Match()` instead raises exception, and you have to deal with it with that pesky `On Error...` construction.

One notable difference is that variable, being assigned to, MUST be of type `Variant`, since only this type can hold `Error` type.

EXAMPLE:

```vb
Dim vRow As Variant
Dim seek_date As Date
Dim rngDate As Range
seek_date = DateSerial(2023, 12, 26)
'// Search for date in column "A"
vRow = Application.Match(seek_date, Columns(1), 0)
'// vRow can hold Error object. That is why it is Variant.
'// Check if it does not hold Error (i.e. date was found).
If Not IsError(vDate) Then
  '// OK. Date was found. Deal with it.
  '// vRow holds numeric value (row number).
  '// For example, get the range with date:
  Set rngDate = Cells(vRow, 1)
Else
  '// Date was not found
End If
```

Answer (score -1):

Update: I've modified the code below to set the active cell before the find. The second animated gif show the code running

One approach is to do a find based upon the specific date format, which in your case appears to be `"[$-en-US]dd-mmm;@"`.  The following is a simple example, which you could then adjust to your need.  To make this example work, place 3 dates into "A1:A3", with just one of them having the desired format, and then run the macro.  The animated gif shows how to set the format.

[image]

```
Sub dateFormatFind()
Dim sh As Worksheet, searchR As Range
Dim cell As Range, resultR As Range
Set sh = Worksheets("Sheet5")
Set searchR = sh.Range("A1:A3")
Set resultR = sh.Range("C1")
sh.Range("A1").Activate
Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = "[$-en-US]dd-mmm;@"
resultR = searchR.Find(What:="", After:=ActiveCell, _
LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=True)
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I get a generic error 1004 when I try to set the FindFormat exactly as you outlined above.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out.  Perhaps it's because I had cell A1 activated when I ran the code and you did not.  In any case, I've now modified the code to make sure that doesn't happen, and provided an animated gif to show the code running.

Answer (score -1):

To search for dates, first you have to save it in a `String` variable and give it the format `"Short Date"`. Then `Find` the variable by converting it to date.

This function is quite generic but easy to adapt to any question.
Write the function and its call in a standard module. In `ActiveSheet` write the date 25/12/2023 in the format you want (for example 25-dic-23) and launch the `DateFind_Call` call

```
Option Explicit

Public Function DateFind(ByVal shSheet_I As Worksheet, ByVal dDate_I As Date) As String
    DateFind = ""
    Dim StrDate As String
    StrDate = Format(dDate_I, "Short Date")
    
    Dim DateCell As Range
    Set DateCell = shSheet_I.Cells.Find( _
        What:=CDate(StrDate), _
        After:=Range("A1"), _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Not DateCell Is Nothing Then
        DateFind = DateCell.Address(False, False)
    End If
End Function

Sub DateFind_Call()
    Dim MyDate As String
    MyDate = DateFind(ActiveSheet, CDate("25/12/2023"))
    If MyDate <> "" Then
        MsgBox "Date found in range: """ & MyDate & """"
    Else
        MsgBox "Date not found"
    End If
End Sub
```

Visit https://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/find-dates.htm for more details.