# Match Textbox entry with cells to populate column with Userform data

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have multiple spreadsheets with a row of dates for each employee. 
Within the userform that pops up modified for each employee, there is a place for the date at the top, and they fill out the rest of the information and then submit.
Is there a way to match up the date on the sheet with the one on the userform to populate the column underneath?

Comment: Do you mean if they enter a duplicate date?

Comment: More so if they submit the form twice, each time it will enter as a new column, regardless if the date is the same. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: I can't see where the date comes into it in your code - at the moment it will just add to a new column which is not what you want.  So it needs to check if the date already exists - but where's the date?  I take it it's on `Sheet2` somewhere and you have a textbox on the form that you enter the date into which is transferred to the sheet when you click the button?

Comment: edited, hope that gives you more info. Basically just searching for the most efficient way of re-writing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a textbox on your form that you type the date into.

This first bit of code is ensuring you have a date in the textbox rather than anything else.

Paste this into a normal module.  You can place it in the form, but in a module allows it to be used by any other forms you may have that contain a date.

```
Public Sub FormatDate(ctrl As Control)

    Dim dDate As Date
    Dim IsDate As Boolean

    On Error GoTo ERR_HANDLE

    If Replace(ctrl.Value, " ", "") <> "" Then
        On Error Resume Next
            dDate = CDate(ctrl.Value)
            IsDate = (Err.Number = 0)
            On Error GoTo -1
        On Error GoTo ERR_HANDLE

        If IsDate Then
            ctrl.Value = Format(ctrl.Value, "dd-mmm-yyyy")
            ctrl.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        Else
            ctrl.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End If
    End If

EXIT_PROC:
        On Error GoTo 0
        Exit Sub

ERR_HANDLE:
        MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbOKOnly, "FormatDate()"
        Resume EXIT_PROC

End Sub
```

Place this on the form as the `AfterUpdate` event for your textbox:

```
Private Sub txtDate_AfterUpdate()

    On Error GoTo ERR_HANDLE

    With Me
        FormatDate .txtDate
    End With

EXIT_PROC:
        On Error GoTo 0
        Exit Sub

ERR_HANDLE:
        MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbOKOnly, "txtDate_AfterUpdate()"
        Resume EXIT_PROC

End Sub
```

Any valid date will be formatted as *dd-mmm-yyyy*, any invalid date will turn the background of the control red.

---

Next you need to find the date on row 1 of your sheet.  Again this can be kept in a normal module so you can use it outside of the form:

```
Public Function FindDate(DateValue As Date) As Range

    Dim rFound As Range

    With Sheet2
        Set rFound = .Rows(1).Find(DateValue, .Cells(1, 1), xlValues, xlWhole)

        If rFound Is Nothing Then
            Set rFound = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1)
        End If

    End With

    Set FindDate = rFound

End Function
```

This will return the cell that the date is in or the last blank cell on row 1 if the date isn't found.

I'm not sure if you want this bit, but this then finds the last cell containing data in a specified column number:

```
Public Function LastCell(wrksht As Worksheet, Col As Long) As Range

    Dim lLastRow As Long

    On Error Resume Next
        lLastRow = wrksht.Columns(Col).Find("*", , , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Row
    On Error GoTo 0

    If lLastRow = 0 Then lLastRow = 1

    Set LastCell = wrksht.Cells(lLastRow, Col)

End Function
```

---

Now you just need to attach the code to your find button to return the first blank cell beneath the date you specify:

```
Private Sub btnFind_Click()

    Dim rFoundCell As Range

    'First blank cell beneath date.
    Set rFoundCell = LastCell(Sheet1, FindDate(CDate(Me.txtDate)).Column).Offset(1)

End Sub
```

---

If you just wanted to find the date you can just use:

```
Set rFoundCell = FindDate(CDate(Me.txtDate))
```

The help file on `Find` is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find).

Finding dates can be problematic in Excel:

- [excel-vba-range-find-date-that-is-a-formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45639660/excel-vba-range-find-date-that-is-a-formula)
- [DateTimeVBA](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DateTimeVBA.htm#Finding)