# Set Rng comes up as Nothing

Tags: excel, vba, named-ranges

I would like some help on the below if you can.

I'm working between 2 workbooks and I want from the first one to find the value of Cell("B6") which happens to be a date on the second Workbook in column B. Although it seems that the code finds the date when it comes to set it as a range it comes as empty. Can you please help me to see what I'm doing wrong.

I'm a novice in VBA and I'm trying with an online search to make my life easier.
Thank you in advance.

```
Sub Update_Forecast_2()
    Dim myFile As String
    Dim YourFolderPath As Variant
    Dim FindString As Date
    Dim newFile As String
    FindString = CLng(Date)
    Dim Rng As Range

    YourFolderPath = "C:\Users\konstand\Desktop\Forecast"
    ChDir YourFolderPath
    myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename
    If myFile = "False" Then Exit Sub
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=myFile
    newFile = Replace(myFile, YourFolderPath + "\", "")

    Range("B6").Select
    Workbooks("Forecast file.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Forecast_Sort").Activate
    Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = myFile
    Workbooks(newFile).Activate
    Range("B6").Activate
    FindString = Workbooks(newFile).Sheets("Forecast").Range("B6").Value
    'MsgBox FindString
    If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
        With Workbooks("Forecast file").Sheets("Forecast_Sort").Range("B:B")
            Set Rng = .Find(What:=DateValue(FindString), _
                            After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False)
            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
            Rng.Select
            End If
            Workbooks("Forecast file.xlsm").Activate
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Following Erjon's request in order to help you more to understand what I'm trying to do I attached 2 pictures and kind of explained something. I hope I helped and didn't make it more confusing.

So I have the main file on which I want to see the changes

[Main File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54xFf.png)

Then I have the file from which I want to take the updated values every week if not more frequently. Be aware that this file every time will have a different name, such as "Wk09Update.xlsx", "Wk10Update.xlsx", "Wk11Update.xlsx", .......

Though before I go to the new file to copy and paste the new values I want on the main file from the date that the new file starts to copy the values from columns H,I, & J and paste them on top of the existing values in columns C, D, & E. Then I want to go to the new file and copy/paste the updated values from there to columns H,I, & J on the main file so I can see the diffenerces from a week to week update.

[New File(Wk11Update.xlsx)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxGGD.png)

[How it should be after Wk12Update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTJAa.png)

[What I'm trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOID1.png)

[Object Variable or With block Variable not set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4Ung.png)

Comment: I always have issues when setting something with all the options. Does `Set Rng = .Find(DateValue)` work?

Comment: Dates can be tricky, https://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/find-dates.htm

Comment: Hard to say. Even without the DateValue still, Rng comes up as nothing.

Comment: Please indicate on what line you get the error/problem. Also you use *select*. That's an error in itself. Don't

Comment: Here is the problem:
When I run the Macro by using a breakpoint Set Rng= appears as Nothing but 
FindString appears as it should (05/03/2019). 
Set Rng = .Find(What:=DateValue(FindString), _
                            After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False)

Comment: Your problem with finding Dates is explained and a solution given at [Excel VBA Range.Find Date That is a Formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45639660/excel-vba-range-find-date-that-is-a-formula). One problem with your code is that 'DateValue` returns a `Date` datatype which does not exist in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to make your code simple for example you have a lot of .Activate.
This will for sure in some point lead you into confusion.

you have to declare first all your worksheets and workbooks like this:

```
Sub Test()
dim book1 as workbook 'a workbook
dim book2 as workbook 'another workbook

dim SheetOfBook1 as worksheet 
dim SheetOfBook2 as worksheet 

set book1 = workbooks("NameOfWorkbook1.xlsm")
set book2 = workbooks("NameOfWorkbook2.xlsm")

set SheetOfBook1 = book1.worksheets("NameOfSheet")
set SheetOfBook2 = book2.worksheets("NameOfSheet")

'at this point you can check everything you want without activating something for example

 SheetOfBook1.range("A1") = SheetOfBook2.Range("A1") 'or whatever

'if you want to check if a value in book1 exists in book2 then do a loop

 dim cell as range

 for each cell in SheetOfBook2.Range("A1:A100).Cells
    If SheetOfBook1.range("A1") = Cell.Value Then
       msgbox "I founded what you are searching for"
    End If
 Next Cell
 End Sub
```

So you have to eliminate all this .activate, use loops etc. As for your example can you edit your question and can you illustrate with an image what you want to achieve?

**Edit**

If you want to open workbooks based on weeknumber i have this following code:

```
Sub Test()
Dim Main As Workbook
Dim Update As Workbook

Dim ForecastSort As Worksheet
Dim Forecast As Worksheet

Dim CheckIfOpen
Dim WeekNumber As String
Dim FirstDayInWeek

Dim FirstDayOfWeekRow As Long

Dim lRowUpdate As Long

Set Main = Workbooks("Main.xlsm")
Set ForecastSort = Main.Worksheets("Forecast_Sort")

'The code below will open the workbook which for name has the number week of today date automatically----------------------------------------------

 WeekNumber = WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(Date) + 1 'The requested week

 CheckIfOpen = IsWorkBookOpen("C:\Users\Erjon-PC\Desktop\Forecast\Wk" & 
 WeekNumber & "Update.xlsx") 'Checks if the update workbook is opened or not

 FirstDayInWeek = Date - Weekday(Date, vbUseSystem) + 2 'First day of requested week

 FirstDayOfWeekRow = ForecastSort.Range("B:B").Find(FirstDayInWeek).Row 'Finds the row of the start day of the requested week in main book


If CheckIfOpen = True Then
    Set Update = Workbooks("Wk" & WeekNumber & "Update.xlsx")
Else
    Set Update = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Erjon-PC\Desktop\Forecast\Wk" & WeekNumber & "Update.xlsx")
End If
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Set Forecast = Update.Worksheets("Forecast")

lRowUpdate = Forecast.Cells(Forecast.Rows.Count, "W").End(xlUp).Row 'Last row in column W in update book

Forecast.Range("W2:Y" & lRowUpdate).Copy

ForecastSort.Range("H" & FirstDayOfWeekRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Update.Close savechanges:=False

End Sub

Function IsWorkBookOpen(FileName As String)
Dim ff As Long, ErrNo As Long

On Error Resume Next
ff = FreeFile()
Open FileName For Input Lock Read As #ff
Close ff
ErrNo = Err
On Error GoTo 0

Select Case ErrNo
Case 0:    IsWorkBookOpen = False
Case 70:   IsWorkBookOpen = True
Case Else: Error ErrNo
End Select
End Function
```

The above code will open the workbook that has the week number in it's name, today it will open Wk11Update.xlsx, the next week it will open Wk12Update.xlsx.

If you want to open books that has for name future dates just add +1 or more to this code:

```
WeekNumber = WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(Date) + 1 'The requested week
```

Then in the opened book it will find last row with data in the column W, it will copy 3 column starting from W, and paste them in the column H of main book. The data will be pasted in the row where the first day of requested week is.

Comment: I attached pictures as you asked. 
The reason that I didn't proceed as you suggest is that the new file would change the name every week if not more frequently and due to the fact that I'm not an experienced user on VBA I was afraid that I would do more damage than good.

Comment: There is not the problem in the name of the workbook. Anyway i will analyze your files and respond to you today. :)

Comment: I updated my answer, please can you check it and explain me more?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Erjon. I really appreciate it. 
The macro for opening the files is perfect. I will update my post with 2 more pictures so I can help you more understand what I want. 

Again thank you for your time.

Comment: It's very simple to do what you want, in the main book we will find the row of the day which starts the week, there we will paste the data. I will update my code later to fit your request

Comment: As I'm waiting for your update, I would like to ask you something regarding the file opening. As normal according to the dates we are currently running on Wk 11 but the forecast that is being published every Monday or Tuesday is for the next week. That means that we should be opening Wk12Update and not Wk11Update and because I'm not sure how to change it on your macro can you take it under consideration ?

Comment: I updated the code, sorry for the delay, to accomplish what you want you have to learn a little bit VBA, it is very easy so to open the book which for name has the next week you have to add 1 to the variable which finds the week so: WeekNumber = WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(Date) + 1. Anyway i updated the code. Write me again if you will have troubles. Also i have commented the code. Just check if we can copy the desidered data, than analyzing my code you will find how to move them in the column C.

Comment: Sorry for the late responce, I tried the updated code and although everything seems fine when it reaches to the point that you will see the in attached picture it gives error. I'm attaching the picture in my original post.

Comment: The dates in column B in the main file, are them real data or text?

Comment: They are custom formated as the original file. 
The custom format is like this [$-en-US]dd/mmm;@

Comment: then you have to check the name of workbooks, does they have extensions .xlsm, .xlsx or .xlx, check the names of realted worksheets, cause i have puted them just for test. you have to change them as they are in your files.

Comment: Put my code in a module so you can debug it better.