# How to use Range.find or Match function in VBA for row of dates not formatted as dates?

Tags: excel, vba

**I need to find the column value in the range that matches a user-inputted date.**

I have a range where one of the rows has dates of the month that are purposefully not formatted as dates.

I tried using the .find method and application.match but both are not working for me (even though it's guaranteed that the user inputted date is within the range).

Below are the relevant portions of code:

```
Dim vCurrentDate As Variant
Dim iCurrentDateCol As Integer
Dim rRng As Range

'Sheet8.Range("s1") is formatted as yyyy/mm/dd
vCurrentDate = Sheet8.Range("s1")

'HolidaySchedule is for C$5:$AJ$90
'The row with dates has dates formatted as "Monday", "Tuesday", etc"
Set rRng = Sheet3.Range("HolidaySchedule")
```

> ATTEMPT 1: Using Application.Match (Similarly tried with Worksheetfunction)
>   Result: Run-time error '424' Object required

```
'I have tried vCurrentDate, vCurrentDate.value, vCurrentDate.Value2
iTestCurrentDateCol = Application.Match(vCurrentDate.Value2, rRng, 0)
```

> ATTEMPT 2: Using .Find

```
iTestCurrentDateCol = rRng.Find(vCurrentDate.Value2, LookIn:=xlValues)
```

Comment: Attempt 2 will certainly not work because `Find` returns a range object, not an integer (use Long anyway).

Comment: Could you supply some sample data? I just tried your combination of formats and it worked just fine. Also, have you tried a simple MATCH function in the worksheet (without using VBA) to see where the problem lies?

Comment: @SJR - would it work if I Dim iTestCurrentDateCol as Range then find the value of iTestCurrentDateCol?

Comment: @M.Schalk: Using Match function in the worksheet works correctly for me (returns: 21)

Assume vCurrentDate = 18/09/2019
Assume F6:AJ6 have text values of Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, etc....corresponding to 01/09/2019, 02/09/2019, 03/09/2019, etc

Comment: Yes, that's the way to do it, check that Find returns something and if so use the column property of a range. Dates can be tricky, eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45639660/excel-vba-range-find-date-that-is-a-formula

Comment: @M.Schalk - Figured out how to do it with .Match - just need to do .Match (CDbl(vCurrentDate),rRng,0) and it works

Comment: @SJR if I do set iTestCurrentDateCol = rRng.Find(CDbl(vCurrentDate), LookIn:=xlValues), itestCurrentDateCol is "Nothing" whereas using the .Match works

Comment: I would start by specifying all `Find` parameters as they are often not as you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from the comments, here's the answer to my own question for my own question for attempt 1 if anyone is curious:

```
iTestCurrentDateCol = Application.Match(CDbl(vCurrentDate), rRng, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work like this:

```
Dim SomeValue As String: SomeValue = ""
Dim Adress As Range
Dim Int As Variant

Set Adress = Sheets(1).Range("A:A").Find(SomeValue)
Int = Adress.Value
```

vCurrentDate might still be a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the code! I did something like this but still doesn't work for me, even if I use set Adress = rRng.Find(CDbl(vCurrentDate),lookin:=xlvalues)

If  Adress Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Nothing"
Else
    Int = Adress.value
    Msgbox Int
End If

Msgbox shows up as "Nothing" even though I've found the date using .Match works