# Find a date which is represented with a formula

Tags: excel, vba

**I assign the 1st January to cell A1. The cell formula bar displays:**
01/01/2020

**The cell is then formatted as Custom:**
ddd", "ddmmm
**So the cell displays:**
Wed, 01Jan

I can use the following code to select the cell A1 (1st Jan):

> `ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(#1/1/2020#, , lookat:=xlWhole).Select`

**I assign the 2nd of Jan to cell A4. Cell A4 is formatted the same custom way and the formula bar displays:**
A1+1

**The cell displays:**
Thu, 02Jan

When searching for the 2nd of Jan i'm getting Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set error, when I run the macro as:

> `ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(#2/1/2020#, , lookat:=xlWhole).Select`

How can I correct the macro to find and select cell A4 that represents the cell for 2nd Jan?

Comment: Are you certain that #2/1/2020# is `2-Jan-2020`?  VBA can be US-Centric sometimes.

Comment: Thanks Ron, you are correct that #2/1/2020# is actually a search for the 1st of Feb but my problem is still that I can't search/ find dates in cells that are created by adding an integer to a previous date. I'd like to keep this way of generating the dates if possible. Any ideas?

Comment: See [Excel VBA Range.Find Date That is a Formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45639660/excel-vba-range-find-date-that-is-a-formula)

Answer (score 0):

You may try this,

- Do ctrl+F in your datasheet
- Click Options<<
- Set Look In: Values

[image]

Comment: Thanks Vikash but I want to incorporate this into a macro without using Find and Replace in way you have shown.

Comment: I want you to just do it once in your datasheet and then try to run the macro, if it gives you the correct output. This is just to save the Find and Replace setting in your workbook.

Answer (score 0):

In order to determine if a cell contains a formula, you might use the `=FORMULATEXT()` worksheet function: when there is no formula in that particular same, this worksheet function returns an empty string (`""`).