# Problems with .find and Date within different Excel Applications/Instances

Tags: excel, vba, date, find

Hoping someone might have a clue if there is anything I can do to work around the problem I am having.  It might be difficult to add the code in I am using as it is so big.

I have a table with calendar dates in the first column.  They are all in dd/mm/yyyy format.  In VBA I want to search for a date and find the row number within the calendar using the following;

`FirstRow = Workbooks(WorkbookSelected.Name).Sheets("Tables").Columns(1).Find(ConfirmedDate, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookAt:=xlWhole).Row`

The Confirmed Date is stored as a Date variable, taken from the calendar as well, but it gets days added to it.  I am searching in two different workbooks to find the FirstRow.  If both workbooks are in the same application/instance of excel then this code works fine.

But if I open the 2nd workbook in a new instance of excel, it errors because the date isn't found.  Something is happening with the date in the 2nd application.  If I use `format(ConfirmedDate, "dd/mm/yyyy")` it will find it in the 2nd workbook.  But that code won't work in the original workbook.  Similar code to above, but just referencing the Excel Instance it needs to look into.  I get the Runtime Error 91 when it won't find it.

`FirstRow = ExcelInstanceSelected.Workbooks(WorkbookSelected.Name).Sheets("Tables").Columns(1).Find(ConfirmedDate, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookAt:=xlWhole).Row`

`FirstRow = ExcelInstanceSelected2.Workbooks(2ndWorkbookSelected.Name).Sheets("Tables").Columns(1).Find(ConfirmedDate, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookAt:=xlWhole).Row`

I am trying to find a way to find the date in the calendar regardless of which excel application I am using.  I have tried opening the workbook with the local set to true (doesn't help).  I have tried combinations of format, cdate, cdbl, lookin:=xlformulas.  Nothing will work with both workbooks.

It is driving me nuts.  I can only assume that the .find in the 2nd workbook is changing the format of the stored ConfirmedDate to the US format of m/dd/yyyy.  I just can't find a way to ensure both dates can be formatted to dd/mm/yyyy regards of how they start.

Many thanks for any help.

Cel

Comment: Why use `Workbooks(WorkbookSelected.Name).Sheets` as opposed to just `WorkbookSelected.Sheets`?

Comment: It is just the way I originally learned how to use looking at different workbooks.  I can certainly change it, but that doesn't fix this issue.  It is finding the correct workbook.

Comment: I didn't imply it would fix the issue, just didn't really make any sense. It's like saying `SUM(1+2) = 3` instead of `3 = 3`. You are unnecessarily using a function _(`Workbooks()`)_ to get a workbook object, when you ___already have___ the workbook object.

Comment: I appreciate you pointing it out, I will change it within my code.

Comment: You don't really need to change it, I just thought I would point that out. You can't learn if we never say anything :-)

Comment: It is a good thing to point out.  It will dramatically reduce the size of my code. Part of the problem of just learning myself, I am sure I have done many things which are not the best way of doing it.

Comment: Excel does not have a **date** data type. Dates are stored as serial numbers with `1`= `1-Jan-1900` or `1-Jan-1904`.  VBA does have a **date** datatype and finding dates on an excel worksheet can be tricky. Take a look at [Excel VBA Range.Find Date That is a Formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45639660/excel-vba-range-find-date-that-is-a-formula)

Comment: @K.Davis - Something to note.  I tried to change the workbook objects as you suggested, unfortunately it will not work with having to select the Excel Application.  But it is useful if I am only using one instance.  So thank you.

Comment: @Ron - I quickly tested the loop you had to find dates, while this worked, I don't know if it is something I can use currently (timescales are too short to fix the code).  

I still don't understand why searching for UK Dates works in one workbook, but the date gets converted to US format when searching in New Applications.  

I can get a work around by changing the format of the dates within the tables to not change with the regional settings.  But this would then require putting format() into each .find.

Comment: Searching for the underlying number in Excel is relatively foolproof. It sounds like either way, you are going to have to modify your code.