# ".Find Date" Breaks at mid point in month

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a function to find a cell that matches a date that is 6 days prior to the currently selected one. It works fine for all the dates 'after' the 15th of the month. 
Prior to the 15th of the month it breaks....? Does anyone know why? is this my fault somehow?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
Private Function FindUpperDateCellAddress(stringUpperDate) As Range

Set FindUpperDateCellAddress = Range("D:D").Find(stringUpperDate, LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)


If FindUpperDateCellAddress Is Nothing Then
'Do nothing
MsgBox "Sorry, I have not been able to find an upper cell address.", vbCritical, "Oops"
End
Else
upperBoundCellAddress = FindUpperDateCellAddress.Address

End If


End Function
```

To explain a little more. I need the cell address of the date that is 6 days prior to the one I'm using. They are not sequentially behind but could be separated by 50 or more rows.

I have tried using the date as a string, as a date, reformatting it, re formatting the sheet itself to ensure the cell is a date cell.

Note: the date that it is searching for is 'generated' via a formula in the cell. So the cell isn't directly a date.

Thanks.

Comment: What is `upperBoundCellAddress `

Comment: Also what format is the data in column D?

Comment: Hi, in reply to your first...nothing, it was left over from struggling with the problem. In answer to the second it is: dd-mmm-yy

Comment: In that case, what is the formula that returns the date?

Comment: I think the issue we are facing at the moment is not knowing what data type we need to evaluate.

Comment: I think you are right. (I commented the same on your second answer).

Comment: I've tested (using my 2nd answer) on a new worksheet. I added dates between 01-Apr-20  to 31-Apr-20 as text values in Column E. In the cell next these in column D, I added to the formula bar `=E1 + 1`. I had column D formatted as Number and then as Short Date, then as Custom (dd-mmm-yy). When running my test the results in the immediate window were  consistant, the `.Value` for each was relevant to the formatting of the cell (be it number or short date) and the address was `$D$15` for all tests. I think you'll need to update your question with more info about the data being evaluated?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do it avoiding the `.Find` method is to loop through your range to find the data.

I've also specified the range rather than search the entire column by locating the `LastRow` being the last used row and using that in our `Set` statement for the range.

```
Private Function FindUpperDateCellAddress(ByVal stringUpperDate As String) As Range

Dim RangeToSearch As Range
Dim CellToSearch As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim convertedDate As Date

convertedDate = CDate(stringUpperDate)

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
Set RangeToSearch = Range("D1:D" & LastRow) 

'This searches from Cell D1 to the last used Cell in column D
For Each CellToSearch In RangeToSearch
    If CellToSearch.Value = convertedDate Then
        Set FindUpperDateCellAddress = CellToSearch
        Exit For
    Else
        'Do nothing
    End If
Next CellToSearch

If FindUpperDateCellAddress Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Sorry, I have not been able to find an upper cell address.", vbCritical, "Oops"
    Exit Function
End If
End Function
```

Comment: I have tried both your solutions an still I have a problem. In fact both of them resulted in not being able to find any dates regardless off the starting point being after the 15th or not...Clearly I have something wrong. I have tried changing the format of the column to different date formats. This is most likely my error but is there any significance when dealing with cells that are 'displaying' a date pulled up by a formula as opposed to one that is directly written in?

Comment: If you change the cell format to `Number`, do you get a numeric value or does it remain as `15-Apr-20` for example?

Comment: Note I've edited this answer to include a missing `Exit For` escape.

Comment: If I change the formatting of the cells, the cells change to numbers. However I still get a date from the variables.

Comment: Maybe relevant, the 'dates' are generated from the first cell in a column that is linked to another sheet. each subsequent row down is essentially the first cell +1 then +2 etc etc. So the 'date' for the 10 cell for example is a formula like D6+9 .

Comment: So in a nutshell, where I can select the date I want, I am subtracting 6 days from that 'date' to get the date that I want for part of my range. However, matching/finding that date is my stumbling block....just thinking, would it be possible to not find the date, but rather the underlying formula. in this case....D6+2? so rather than cell.Value, something like cell.Formula?

Comment: Well dates in Excel have a serial number associated with them starting from 01/01/1900 (unless you use 1904 date reference). AS such, as long as the numeric value is an applicable date serial, the funciton to find a `Date` value should work fine for you, even if you are adding additional values to it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212471/discussion-between-samuel-everson-and-j4c3n-14).

Comment: Sorry been at work...I have looked at my own attempt and noticed an error. Now fixed along with your example I have managed to get this working. Thanks for all your help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track but some syntax of your function is a little off.

Consider rewriting like this:

```
Private Function FindUpperDateCellAddress(ByVal stringUpperDate As String) As Range

Dim upperBoundCellAddress As String
Dim RangeToSearch As Range

Set RangeToSearch = Range("D:D").Find(stringUpperDate, LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)


If RangeToSearch Is Nothing Then
    'Do nothing
    MsgBox "Sorry, I have not been able to find an upper cell address.", vbCritical, "Oops"
    Exit Function
Else
    upperBoundCellAddress = RangeToSearch.Address
End If

Set FindUpperDateCellAddress = Sheet1.Range(upperBoundCellAddress)
End Function
```

And call it from a subroutine like:

```
Sub TestDate()

Dim myDate As Range

Set x = FindUpperDateCellAddress("14/04/2020")

Debug.Print "The date found was: " & x.Value
Debug.Print "The Address found was: " & x.Address

End Sub
```

This will find `"14/04/2020"` in `Column D` on `Sheet` based on the below data on the sheet.

**NOTE:** this will only find the date as a `String` meaning it will only find it if the date is written as text value, not a date value. *See below this example for how to search a date value.*

[image: example values on sheet1]

Based on that example data, the following will be printed to the immidiate window of the VBE:

```
The date found was: 14/04/2020
The Address found was: $D$14
```

For the same results but searching for a `date` value, change this to the function:

```
Dim convertedDate As Date

convertedDate = CDate(stringUpperDate)

Set RangeToSearch = Range("D:D").Find(convertedDate, LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
```

Comment: @J4C3N-14 FYI searching for a `string` or `date` value is really determined by the formatting/actual value in your search range. You should be able to easily modify the function and sub for your date formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dates are "real" dates (and I assume they are since, when you change the format to general, they change to a number), arguably the most robust method is to loop through the values looking for the date in question.

Note that we use the `.Value2` property of the range object since this will be the unformatted value.

So your function code might look like:

```
Option Explicit
Private Function FindUpperDateCellAddress(stringUpperDate As Date) As Range

    Dim C As Range
    Dim R As Range

With Worksheets("sheet1")
    Set R = .Range(.Cells(1, 4), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp))
End With

For Each C In R
    If Int(C.Value2) = Int(stringUpperDate) Then
        Set FindUpperDateCellAddress = C
        Exit Function
    End If
Next C

MsgBox "Sorry, I have not been able to find an upper cell address.", vbCritical, "Oops"

End Function
```

You may need to make some changes if you are not using `Sheet1` or the column `D` range for your data.

Converting the values to an integer may not be necessary, depending on how exactly your **real data**, and **real stringUpperDate** are being generated

Also take a look at my answer to [Excel VBA Range.Find Date That is a Formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45639660/excel-vba-range-find-date-that-is-a-formula)