# Excel VBA will not locate date

Tags: excel, vba

I am working to create an add on style sheet to my company timesheet that will autofill company paid holidays by just the user inserting the dates. I use formulas on the excel timesheets to autofill the dates for the entire year so that I save time doing my bi-weekly payroll form. I have a holiday sheet that I name the holidays and input the date they are observed. The code is supposed to search all worksheets in the workbook until it finds the date for the corresponding holiday and input the number of hours off, the holiday code and name. The code I have written will find any date I insert up to 11/9/2022 and after this date it will not find any further dates. I have tried many things including changing the date column format, using different criteria settings for the .Find and even removing the formula from the date column and actually writing in 11/11/2022 and it is still unable to locate the date while using .Find. Please any help would be appreciated. I have added a few screens and code snippets of what I have so far.

```
Sub VeteransDay()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim FindString As String
    Dim Rng As Range
    FindString = Sheets("Holiday").Range("B9").Value
    If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
        For Each ws In Worksheets
            If ws.Name <> "Holiday" Then
                With ws.UsedRange
                   Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False)
                       If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                       sheetName = ws.Name
                       Cell_Add = Split(Rng.Address, "$")
                       ThisCol = Cell_Add(1)
                       ThisRow = Cell_Add(2)

                       Worksheets(sheetName).Range("K" & ThisRow).Value = 8
                       Worksheets(sheetName).Range("K" & ThisRow).Font.Color = vbRed
                       Worksheets(sheetName).Range("L" & ThisRow).Value = "HD"
                       Worksheets(sheetName).Range("L" & ThisRow).Font.Color = vbRed
                       Worksheets(sheetName).Range("M" & ThisRow).Value = Range("A9")
                       Worksheets(sheetName).Range("M" & ThisRow).Font.Color = vbRed
                       Exit Sub
                    End If
                End With
            End If
        Next ws
    End If
End Sub
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8Er6.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHXKh.png)

Comment: Try: `Dim DateToFind As Date`, `DateToFind = Sheets("Holiday").Range("B9").Value`, `Set Rng = .Find(What:=Format$(DateToFind, "mm/d/yyyy")...`

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately that did not work either. It worked just as the other way did as it would find dates on and before 11/9/2022 but nothing after that date.

Comment: I have been testing stuff out and have noticed that there are random dates all over the worksheets that will not locate and that they usually coincide with double digit dates.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, the search is restricted to the range B1:B37 on each sheet.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub VeteransDay()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, ar, r
    Dim dt As Date, sName As String, n As Long
    Dim arHoliday, lastrow As Long, i As Long
    
    With Sheets("Holiday")
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        arHoliday = .Range("A1:B" & lastrow).Value
    End With
    
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Holiday" Then
            ' loop through holidays
            For i = 1 To UBound(arHoliday)
                dt = arHoliday(i, 2)
                r = Application.Match(CDbl(dt), ws.Range("B1:B37").Value2, 0)
                If Not IsError(r) Then
                    'MsgBox ws.Name & " row " & r
                    With ws.Range("K" & r)
                        .Value = 8
                        .Offset(, 1) = "HD"
                        .Offset(, 2) = arHoliday(i, 1) ' col A
                        .Resize(, 3).Font.Color = vbRed
                        n = n + 1
                    End With
                End If
            Next
       End If
    Next ws
    MsgBox n & " found for all dates", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm looking over to code you submitted I understand it, but I wonder what was causing my original code to overlook some dates but work for others. Thank you for your help. Now I just need to alter it to iterate over the worksheet with the holidays on it versus having to create 12 more blocks of identical code for the other rows on the holiday worksheet.

Comment: @Dwd3773 using find with dates in formula is tricky as explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45639660/range-find-on-a-date-that-is-a-formula

Comment: @dwd3773 i have updated code to find all dates