# #Value! error using Range.Find in a function

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to compute a sum of data over the past month.

```vb
Function Monthly_volume_given_velocity() As Double
Dim velocity As Double
Dim ind_vit As Integer
Dim ind_today As Integer
velocity= ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value

With Sheets("2022")
    ind_vel = .Range("A5:A13").Find(What:=velocity).Row
    Dim rng As Range
    rng = .Rows("1").Find(What:=Date, LookIn:=xlFormulas)
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then ind_today = rng.Column: Debug.Print ind_today 
        Monthly_volume_given_velocity = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range(.Cells(ind_vel , ind_today - 30), .Cells(ind_vel , ind_today )))
    End With
End Function
```

I get a #Value! error, although in debug mode I get the right value for `Monthly_volume_given_velocity`.

Replacing `ind_today` with its expected value gives no error, so I guess it comes from the `Range.Find` procedure. I got the `If Not rng...` from a different thread but it does not solve this issue.

Comment: It might be worth adding in another `Debug.Print` line there to check the value of `velocity` being searched for - I'm not sure using `Activecell` is best practise here.

Comment: This is a common issue when referring to active anything rather than a  fully qualified thing.  So change active cell to a fully qualified cell, which likely means you will have to pass in the cell reference a a parameter

Comment: maybe `set rng = .Rows("1").Find(What:=Date, LookIn:=xlFormulas)`. Then test if `ind_today = rng.Column` gives you the correct value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a UDF runs on any error, it will return an error that is displayed as `#VALUE` in your sheet.
Now it is hard to tell what exactly fails in the function, but I see some issues:

- A UDF should never rely on `ActiveCell` (or `ActiveSheet`). Excel handles the recalculation, and it can be triggered if the cell with the formula is not active. Pass the cell as parameter.
- `Find` for Date can be tricky, see [Range.Find on a Date That is a Formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45639660/range-find-on-a-date-that-is-a-formula). I would suggest you search for the date manually.
- You miss a `Set` when you assign the result of the Second Find.
- You check if rng is not Nothing (so Find returned something). However, if it didn't find anything, `int_today` will be 0 and the following `Sum` will get an invalid range as parameter.

I reworked your function. Of course, the `Debug.Print`-statements can be deleted once the function works. As said, you will have to pass the cell as parameter in the formula, eg `=Monthly_volume_given_velocity(B1)`.

```
Function Monthly_volume_given_velocity(cell As Range) As Double
    Dim velocity As Double
    Dim ind_vel As Long
    Dim ind_today As Long
    velocity = cell.Offset(0, -1).Value
    Debug.Print "Vel: " & velocity
        
    With Sheets("2022")
        ' Find Velocity Row
        On Error Resume Next
        ind_vel = .Range("A5:A13").Find(What:=velocity).row
        On Error GoTo 0
        If ind_vel = 0 Then Exit Function
        Debug.Print "ind_vel: " & ind_vel
        
        ' Find Date column
        Dim dates As Variant, lastCol As Long
        lastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Debug.Print "lastcol: " & lastCol
        dates = .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, lastCol)
        For ind_today = 1 To lastCol
            Debug.Print ind_today, dates(1, ind_today)
            If dates(1, ind_today) = Date Then Exit For
        Next
        If ind_today > lastCol Then
            Debug.Print "today not found"
            Exit Function ' date not found
        End If
        Debug.Print ind_today
        
        ' Calculate value
        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = Range(.Cells(ind_vel, ind_today - 5), .Cells(ind_vel, ind_today))
        Debug.Print rng.Address
        Monthly_volume_given_velocity = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(rng)
    End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

A range is an object and thus has to be defined using Set, so it has to be

```
Set rng = [...]
```

Plus a remark regarding the .Find method, in case you don't know: The args (LookIn, LookAt etc.) are static, i.e. they are remembered from the last call if not otherwise defined in a new call. This also includes using the Find dialogue in the user interface. To be on the safe side, one should always provide all args with each call.